# setObject equivalent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have obj-c code

```
[dictionary setObject:[[notification object] objectForKey:@"key"] forKey:@"anotherKey"];
```

how can I translate this to swift ? Notification is NSNotification object

I tried

```
dictionary.setValue(notification.valueForKey("key"), forKey: "anotherKey")
```

but app crashes with error (sorry for image, paste doesn't work)

[image]

Comment: `[notification object]` is not translated: `notification.object`. So `...notification.object.valueForKey("key")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pure Swift equivalent is

```
dictionary["anotherKey"] = notification.object?["key"]
```

If `notification.object` or the key `key` does not exist no object will be assigned.

**Note**:

Never use `valueForKey` / `setValue:forKey:` unless you have a distinct idea  why you are using KVC.

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be it helps you:

```
dictionary .setValue(notification.object["key"], forKey: "anotherKey")
```

Comment: Do **not** use `setValue:forKey` unless you can explain why you are using explicitly KVC.

Answer (score 1):

How about making your dict a `var` (not `let`) and doing this:

```
dictionary["anotherKey"] = [[notification object] objectForKey:@"key"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary["anotherKey"] = (notification.object!["key"] as! String)
```